# JSONPath with hamcrest hasSize()

Tags: citrus-framework

When using the hasSize matcher in the form of @assertThat(hasSize(x))@ with a jsonpath expression that returns an array, duplicate values will not be taken into account.  Example :

```
{
        "a":[
        {
        "value1":"ab",
        "value2": 2
        },
        {
        "value1":"ab",
        "value2":2
        }
        ]
}
```

If I execute payload().validate("$..value1", "@assertThat(hasSize(2))@") it will result in an error as hasSize will expect a collection of size 1 instead of 2.  Is this the desired behavior of the matcher?  A workaround would be to use the expression "$.a[?(@.value1)]".

Comment: I tracked down the problem and it has to do with the values `"ab"` being identical. The hamcrest matcher would work if they were different, e.g. `"ab"` and `"abc"`. This is not intended and a bug. I have opened a GitHub issue for this, see [here](https://github.com/christophd/citrus/issues/277). For now, I have not found an easy workaround but as soon as I find one, I'll post it here.

Comment: Thanks for finding the bug.  Just wanted to let you know that you used the term hasLength instead of hasSize in your issue.

Comment: You're right, I updated the issue. I still used `hasSize` in my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

This is a bug in Citrus. As mentioned in my comment, I have tracked down the bug, see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/christophd/citrus/issues/277).

I have also fixed the bug and opened a [GitHub Pull Request](https://github.com/christophd/citrus/pull/278). However, it may take some weeks for my changes to be reviewed by the main Citrus maintainer, since he is currently working on a different project.

I am positive that the fix will be included in the next Citrus maintenance release `2.7.3`.

### Notes

This bug only occurs if some of the values are duplicate entries, due to a [code fragment](https://github.com/christophd/citrus/blob/4b78c103f262b0af1950605c2c6d15c7b7e979f0/modules/citrus-core/src/main/java/com/consol/citrus/validation/matcher/hamcrest/HamcrestValidationMatcher.java#L183) which uses a `Set`, which by definition cannot hold duplicate entries.

#### Example (copied from the GitHub Issue)

```json
{
  "test_array": [
    {
      "key_with_identical_values": "identical_value",
      "key_with_unique_values": "unique_value"
    },
    {
      "key_with_identical_values": "identical_value",
      "key_with_unique_values": "different_unique_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Given the Citrus validation as follows:

```xml
<receive endpoint="testServer">
  <message type="json">
    <validate>
      <json-path expression="$..key_with_unique_values" value="@assertThat(hasSize(2))@"/>
      <json-path expression="$..key_with_identical_values" value="@assertThat(hasSize(2))@"/>
    </validate>
  </message>
</receive>
```

Even though the JSONPath array for both expressions is of size `2` (`["unique_value", "different_unique_value"]` and `["identical_value", "identical_value"]`), the validation will fail for the expression `$..key_with_identical_values` with the message:

```
Expected: a collection with size <2>
     but: collection size was <1>
```

Comment: @richard-carrasco Good news, my pull request has been merged into the Citrus main line. So, it'll be included in the next maintenance release `2.7.3`.